# A proper way to restrict access to an interface?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class that represents a printing job: `CPrintingJob`. It knows nothing of the document being printed, just the job state - whether the job was queued, rejected, carried on etc.

The idea is an object of this class is instantiated whenever some printing needs to be done, then passed to the printing module along with other data, then the job's creator checks its state to see how printing is going.

Suppose `CPrintingJob` inherits two interfaces:

```
class IPrintingJob // this one is to check the job state
{
    virtual TState GetState() const = 0;
    // ... some other state-inquiring methods

    class ICallback // job's owner is notified of state changes via this one
    {
        virtual void OnStateChange( const IPrintingJob& Job ) = 0; 
    };
};
```

and

```
class IPrintingJobControl // this one is for printing module to update the state
{
    virtual void SetState( const TState& NewState ) = 0;
    // ... some other state-changing methods
};
```

Problem is, the class that creates a `CPrintingJob` object shouldn't have access to the `IPrintingJobControl`, but the printing module `CPrintingJob` is being passed to must be able to change its state and, therefore, have access to that interface.

I suppose this is exactly the case where friends should be used but I have always avoided them as an inherently flawed mechanic and consequently have no idea of how to use them properly.

So, how **do** I do it properly?

Comment: A Factory! The factory creation should return an `IPrintingJob` object that is actually a `CPrintingJob`. Then passing the pointer onward via a cast to CPrintingJob.

Comment: Friend is a flawed mechanic? Where did you get that from? Not using friend leads to bad design, in which you overexpose the inner workings of your classes.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I 100% agree with you, but I still remember that every teacher I ever had in regards to C++ considered friends to be evil..

Comment: Friending leads too strong coupling between components. You're usually better off if you can avoid it, but if you can't, it's a lot better than overexposing your privates :D

Comment: @MFH Well, it is. But that can be said about pretty much every C++ feature :-)

Comment: Simply pass the object to each consumer as the appropriate interface type instead of the do-everything `CPrintJob`. The consumer can certainly cast it back, but that's their problem.

Comment: @MFH that sentence is really begging to be taken out of context.

Comment: @ltjax: I don't think so, as you can restrict the access of all member functions (which is good) and only allow your friends to ever access you. Therefor friends can be used to reduce coupling (as nobody but your friends can access you)...

Comment: @MFH Isn't that a reaction to what ltjax said, rather than me?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: yep, changed it...

Comment: @Itjax friends are part of the interface of a class. Of course the interface of a class and the class itself will be strongly coupled. I don't understand why you conclude from this that we should avoid friends. In reality, friends are just member functions with a different syntax; don't be fooled by the syntax. Would you avoid member functions because they create strong couplings?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes so how do I define a friend-only interface? Would something like making a protected friend-only GetControlInterface() method in a public interface do?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Adding member functions does indeed introduce stronger coupling, which is why interfaces should ideally be minimal. Syntax should not be underestimated, especially in interfaces! I think that friends are hiding coupling somewhat better than member functions though, which is bad. And it is usually easier and more robust to keep invariants up in a single class. I'm not saying they should be avoided at all costs, but they are often used as "hacks" to access internals of otherwise unrelated classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a factory and have the factory return an instance of IPrintingJob (best wrapped inside a smart_ptr). e.g.:

```
 struct PrintingFactory {
   static auto create() -> std::unique_ptr<IPrintingJob> {
     return std::unique_ptr<IPrintingJob>(new CPrintingJob());//as there is currently no std::make_unique..
   }
 }
```

Once you have to use the JobControl you can simply cast the pointer via std::dynamic_pointer_cast.

Comment: [`unique_ptr` should be the default smart pointer](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_103/). Please don't force silly ownership semantics on the consumers of your interfaces.

Comment: Or even better, make the control-class the factory. Intuitively it makes sense that a job should be bound to one controller, and this gives the controller full control of the job without having to resort to downcasting.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: If there is only one reference to the PrintingJob, I agree, but that can't be deducted from the question... EDIT: As the job is likely to be registered with some controller and at the same time will be held in the user code I consider shared_ptr to be the right tool...

Comment: @MFH it can be deduced from your code: there is only the one it creates. As stated in GOTW #103, you can easily make a shared_ptr out of a unique_ptr at any time. You cannot never change from a shared_ptr, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: got it & replaced it (but switching from unique_ptr to shared_ptr certainly has a performance impact [assuming that make_shared is implemented using only one allocation...]), that's one of the reasons why I normally use share, when multiple references are remotely possible... (See figure 2)

Comment: @MFH The assumption I will have to make, that is, IPrintingJob is actually some other interface entirely, really rubs me the wrong way. As Björn and Eli Iser pointed out, making the control-class the factory is the obvious way; but that would mean it will have to oversee the object destruction too, which unnecesarily bloats its interface and IMO defeats CPrintingJob's purpose entirely. I would like a nice object-oriented substitute to a simple job ID that the job owner has to track; not some sort of a monster :)

Comment: @obamator `unique_ptr` (or `shared_ptr`) does the destruction. It's its responsibility, and it exists so you don't need to intermingle that responsibility into other classes.

Answer (score 0):

After some deliberation I've decided that:

1. This whole thing is definitely more trouble than it's worth;
2. (A slightly modified) version of MFH's answer above is the only, hence the best, way to go.

Thanks everyone for the input, it certainly has been enlightening.